# Switching from dead characters mid-game

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques, character-death

**As a GM, how do I wrap game-caused character switching into the story?**

Suppose I had to murder one of the PCs for great ju... *didactic purposes*. For example, my players refuse to understand the idea behind overpowered monsters (not meant to be fought head-on) or the occasional necessity of thinking (instead of relying on my railroading which, as I specifically mentioned to the players, is *not* going to happen). Whether this is a right thing to do is a separate question.

If more specific details are required: the campaign is about to unfold in the wilderness, and character deaths are most probable inside a dungeon, in the neutral-but-suspicious-lizardfolk camp in the forest, that is, at one of the plot's highest-tension points where it would be difficult to justify the appearance of a previously unseen character. I'm not going to kill anyone in a manner that would seem too harsh and undeserved, so death will be an ultimate penalty for extreme mistakes my players make.

**Q:**

- What is the most common/reasonable way of explaining the appearance
  of a new character?
- Does the player have to sit around and wait for
  his new character to appear?
- Is there an established technique
  available to keep the player engaged and the game moving?

I'm talking about a Pathfinder campaign, though there might just be a general rule applicable to a wider set of platforms.

I guess I should also clarify that I strongly disapprove of any "unrealistic" and simpifying measures like instant revival and gold penalty. The story should at least *look* logical.

Comment: Related: [How can I quickly get a player back into a session after their character dies?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13743)

Comment: Knowing that this is Pathfinder/D&Dish is helpful for finding answers, but more information about your specific campaign would be required to give a good answer.

Comment: @Tritium21 what kind of information is required? I added some clarifications.